# How to compile an OpenGL project on Ubuntu?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, visual-studio-code

I am new to OpenGL and I am using Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 18.04.4.

I have a homework and I am provided with a visual studio project. There is a bunch of files that I don't understand. I don't know some of the extensions and how they all work together. How can I compile this project? The files are named like this:

- FragmentShader.fs
- GeometricDefinitions.h
- glad.c
- Object3D.cpp
- Object3D.h
- OpenGLProject.cpp
- OpenGLProject.vcxproj
- ply.h
- plyfile.c
- rectangle.ply
- Shader.h
- VertexShader.sh

I built necessary libraries and ran a sample code to see it works.

Comment: What are you using to compile? It looks like you are asking how to convert a Visual Studio project into a [X] project, but didn't tell us what [X] is. Which IDE are you using? If you are not using an IDE, what are you using? Directly entering compiler commands on the command line (for which compiler)?

Comment: @JaMiT That is actually what I am asking. What should I use to compile these files? I used g++ for the sample code and for IDE I have Visual Studio Code.

Comment: I haven't used Visual Studio Code myself. It looks like VSC doesn't normally use project files, but there might be an extension for that. Opening the directory in VSC might not work so well because of the different file types. :( I can  give an answer as to what the file types are, although I don't know how much that helps.

Answer (score 1):

The files in your directory can be arranged in a few groups:

**C and C++ source files**

These files would be compiled by gcc (or another compiler collection).

- glad.c
- Object3D.cpp
- OpenGLProject.cpp
- plyfile.c

**C and C++ header files**

These files can be ignored by you while building. The compiler will pull them in as needed.

- GeometricDefinitions.h
- Object3D.h
- ply.h
- Shader.h

**OpenGL shaders**

These files (probably) contain OpenGL shader data.

- FragmentShader.fs
- VertexShader.sh

**Polygons?**

I don't recognize this file type, but my guess is that it contains the definition of the surface to which the shaders should be applied.

- rectangle.ply

**Visual Studio project**

This file would be rather useful if you find an IDE extension that allows you to open Visual Studio projects. Without such an extension, it is just a reference for what Visual Studio would do (it should be XML, so human-readable to some extent).

- OpenGLProject.vcxproj

Based on just the file names, I don't know how to make the project work in Visual Studio Code. It would be convenient if there is a Visual Studio Code extension that reads Visual Studio projects (but I don't know of one myself).